# How to process the irregular json file in python to get the serialized values in CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv

```
{\n      \"1 & 1 Internet\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 55,\n        \"abc\": \"low\"\n      },\n      \"1 website hosting\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 0,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"10000ft\": {\n        \"category\": \"Collaboration\",\n        \"xyz\": 48,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"1010data\": {\n        \"category\": \"Big Data\",\n        \"xyz\": 56,\n        \"abc\": \"low\"\n      },\n      \"101domains\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 0,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"111WebHost.com\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 6,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"11Giraffes\": {\n        \"category\": \"Web Design\",\n        \"xyz\": 0,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"123 FlashChat\": {\n        \"category\": \"Collaboration\",\n        \"xyz\": 64,\n        \"abc\": \"medium\"\n      },\n      \"123-Hosts\": {\n        \"category\": \"Web Design & Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 0,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"123-reg\": {\n        \"category\": \"Web Design & Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 52,\n        \"abc\": \"low\"\n      },\n      \"123ContactForm\": {\n        \"category\": \"Survey Solutions\",\n        \"xyz\": 43,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"123LandLord\": {\n        \"category\": \"Asset Management\",\n        \"xyz\": 18,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"123connect\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 8,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"15Five\": {\n        \"category\": \"Telecom\",\n        \"xyz\": 49,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"15MinuteServers\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 13,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"1ShoppingCart\": {\n        \"category\": \"Software Development\",\n        \"xyz\": 27,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"1Web Hosting\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 3,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"1st Domains\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 19,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"1st Easy\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 51,\n        \"abc\": \"low\"\n      },\n      \"1st4webshops\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 12,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"1stDNS Limited\": {\n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 0,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"1time\": {\n        \"category\": \"Expense Management\",\n        \"xyz\": 12,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"2001 Web\": {\n        \"category\": \"Web Design & Infrastructure\",\n        \"xyz\": 24,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"23Video\": {\n        \"category\": \"Content Management\",\n        \"xyz\": 31,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      },\n      \"24 Seven Office\": {\n        \"category\": \"Enterprise Resource Planning\",\n        \"xyz\": 14,\n        \"abc\": \"poor\"\n      }
```

Output:

1 & 1 Internet,Infrastructure,55,low

1 website hosting,Infrastructure,0,poor

......................................

......................................

and so on for the file mentioned above

Comment: Can you please update the bug with the code you have tried till now? And any errors you are getting right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
>>> data = """{\n      \"1 & 1 Internet\": {
...              \n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",
...              \n        \"xyz\": 55,
...              \n        \"ABC\": \"low\"
...              \n      },
...   \n      \"1 website hosting\": {
...              \n        \"category\": \"Infrastructure\",
...              \n        \"xyz\": 0,
...              \n        \"ABC\": \"poor\"
...              \n      },
...   \n      \"10000ft\": {
...              \n        \"category\": \"Collaboration\",
...              \n        \"xyz\": 48,
...              \n        \"ABC\": \"poor\"\n
... }"""
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(data)
...
ValueError: Expecting object: line 30 column 1 (char 489)
```

There is missing closing curly bracket:

```
>>> data = json.loads(data+'}')
>>> for key, value in data.iteritems():
...     print key, value['category'], value['xyz'], value['ABC']
... 
1 & 1 Internet Infrastructure 55 low
10000ft Collaboration 48 poor
1 website hosting Infrastructure 0 poor
```

Comment: Thanks a lot warvariuc ! The problem is I have a irregular json file which has 1000s of line ! The Input wont be as such like you has passed !

Comment: @Arun then you need to research what are the irregularities you have and make the json correct.

Comment: Yeah dude,I'm trying that.I have re-edited the question and gave the input ! You can have a look and gimme ur opinion !

Comment: Your new string works with the code I posted, only change key from 'ABC' to 'abc'